# How to use Laravel all() query for exclude some rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am studding Laravel, I have table name call "projects". To display all projects I used

```
$projects= Project::all();
```

But I have project id array like this, I need to remove this projects from resualts

```
$doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds = array(4, 6, 20);
```

So how to remove above ids project from result, using  **Project::all()**,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using NOT IN? (I haven't tested this, so this is theory...)

```
$projects = Project::whereNotIn('id', $doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds)->get();
```